# Macro to run on the column I have selected

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following macro, it adds a number of zeroes to the beginning of a string of numbers until the number has a total of 7 digits. Currently it only does the A column, I would like for it to run the macro for whichever column I have selected so I do not always have to cut and paste and recut and paste all the columns I need to run it on. ANy ideas?

```
Sub AddZeroes1()
'Declarations
Dim cl As Range
Dim i As Long, endrow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Converts the A column format to Text format
    Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "@"
    'finds the bottom most row
    endrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    '## Or, for Excel 2003 and prior: ##'
    'endrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    'loop to move from cell to cell
    For i = 1 To endrow - 1
        Set cl = Range("A" & i)
        With cl
        'The Do-While loop keeps adding zeroes to the front of the cell value until it         hits     a length of 7
            Do While Len(.Value) < 7
                .Value = "0" & .Value
            Loop
        End With
    Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of defining your columns, use Selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update as many columns as you want by changing the target to the selection rather than a specific column. (as suggested by t.thielemans)

Try this:

```
Sub AddZeroesToSelection()
     Dim rng As Range
     Dim cell As Range

     Set rng = Selection
     rng.NumberFormat = "@"

     For Each cell In rng
        Do While Len(cell.Value) < 7
          cell.Value = "0" & cell.Value
        Loop
     Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: This works for the one cell, but I need it to do it to an entire column.

Comment: It doesn't do it for one cell. It does it for every cell in your selection.

Answer (score 1):

Change only the MyCol line:

```
Sub AddZeroes1()
Dim cl As Range
Dim i As Long, endrow As Long
Dim MyCol As String
MyCol = "A"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Columns(MyCol & ":" & MyCol).NumberFormat = "@"
    endrow = ActiveSheet.Range(MyCol & "1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To endrow - 1
        Set cl = Range(MyCol & i)
        With cl
            Do While Len(.Value) < 7
                .Value = "0" & .Value
            Loop
        End With
    Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**NOT TESTED**

Answer (score 1):

From your question:

> it adds a number of zeroes to the beginning of a string of numbers until the number has a total of 7 digits

If you simply want numbers to show leading 0's until the numbers are 7 digits long, you can use a custom format of: 0000000

For example:

```
    123
   5432
     26
9876543
```

Select the cells -> right-click -> Format Cells -> Custom -> Type in "0000000" (no quotes) -> OK

Now they should appear with the leading 0's:

```
0000123
0005432
0000026
9876543
```

If it has to be a macro, then this should work:

```
Sub AddZeroes1()

    Selection.NumberFormat = "0000000"

End Sub
```